# Flutter - How to add a label that follows the progress position in a LinearProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The title is pretty self explanatory I think.

Basically I need to have a LinearProgressIndicator with a label in the same position as the current progress. Like this:

[image]

I suppose I need to use a `Stack` to create the `Text`, but how can I position it based on the progress of the bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Align widget to align the text in the stack. Use alignment property as Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topLeft, Alignment.topRight, _progressValue);
The progress value should be from 0 to 1

https://dartpad.dev/bbc452ca5e8370bf2fbf48d34d82eb93

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Slider Demo'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new ProgressIndicatorDemo(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProgressIndicatorDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProgressIndicatorDemoState createState() =>
      new _ProgressIndicatorDemoState();
}

class _ProgressIndicatorDemoState extends State<ProgressIndicatorDemo>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // the state that has changed here is the animation object’s value
        });
      });
    controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(animation.value);
    return new Center(
        child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
      LinearProgressIndicator(
        value: animation.value,
      ),
      Align(
          alignment :Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topLeft, Alignment.topRight, animation.value),
          child: Text("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa"),
        ),
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: ```alignment :Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topLeft, Alignment.topRight, animation.value)``` gives an error. Any update on this?

Comment: ```The argument type 'Alignment?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AlignmentGeometry'.```
You can view it on the dartpad by the link given above.

Comment: I did not write the dartpard code but, the error is due to null safety feature which was still in beta I think when I originally wrote the answer. It needs to be modified if you are working in a null safe environment. Try putting ! eg: alignment: Alignment.lerp(Alignment.topLeft, Alignment.topRight, animation!.value)! wherever the error occurs to force flutter to promote the properties and ignore whether they are null. Alternatively, turn off null safety in dart pad before running.

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(children: [
    LinearProgressIndicator(
      value: value,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      color: Colors.blue,
      minHeight: 20,
    ),
    Align(
        alignment:
            AlignmentGeometry.lerp(const Alignment(-1.04, -1), const Alignment(1.04, -1), value)
                as AlignmentGeometry,
        child: Text(
          '${minutes}:${seconds}',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 12),
        )),
  ]);
```